# How to create different stateless widgets depending on constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a custom stateless class with a button:

```
class BottomBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  BottomBtn({
    this.currentName,
    this.name,
    this.iconSize = 24.0,
    this.isSvg = false,
  });

  final String currentName;
  final String name;
  final double iconSize;
  final bool isSVG;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: isSVG
          ? SvgPicture.asset(
              AppAssets.chatSVG,
              color: currentName == name
                  ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                  : Theme.of(context).disabledColor,
              colorBlendMode: BlendMode.srcATop,
            )
          : Image.asset(
              AppAssets.chatSVG,
              color: currentName == name
                  ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                  : Theme.of(context).disabledColor,
              colorBlendMode: BlendMode.srcATop,
            ),
      iconSize: iconSize,
      onPressed: (){},
    );
  }
}
```

Instead of using the switcher `isSVG` I want to have two constructors: `BottomBtn.svg()` and `BottomBtn.image()` depending of use case. How to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to create an abstract class extending StatelessWidget that implements the build method. Then, you can create a class extending from this abstract class and implement nammed constructors.

```
abstract class Parent extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget widget;

  Parent(this.widget);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget;
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  Child.fromSVG(...) : super(SvgPicture.asset(...));
  Child.fromImage(...) : super(Image.asset(...));
}
```